# Dynamic select menu with simple form rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

How can I make a dynamic select menu for regions and cities with simple_form rails?

These are the models:

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :adverts
  has_many :cities
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :region_id
  belongs_to :regions
  has_many :adverts
end
```

This is the form:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :region_id %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :region_id, Category.all, :id, :name %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :city_id %><br />
  <%= f.number_field :city_id %>
</div>
```

I'm looking for help with the simple_form code and the Ajax code.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this particular episode helpful:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus

Comment: This is paid content.

Comment: It's not actually :) Not this episode anyway. You can view it. I've just did it.

Comment: Yes, sorry that's right, just out of date, the revised up to date version of this rails cast is pay for.